# A local ring not a quotient of a regular local ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

In his book *Commutative Ring Theory*, Matsumura proves that if a local ring is equidimensional, and a quotient of a regular local ring, then its completion is equidimensional.

What is an example of a local ring which does not admit such a presentation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A source available online is this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/volume-70/issue-none/Examples-of-bad-Noetherian-local-rings/nmj/1118785530.full) "Examples of bad Noetherian rings" by Marinari (example 2.1).

The reason many of these types of construction work is because of the following vague and counter-intuitive phenomemon:

*It is usually easier than we think for a complete local ring to be a completion of a Noetherian ring with certain properties.*

For example, there is this amazing [theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2154327) by Heitmann that most complete local ring of depth at least $2$ is a completion of a UFD !

So back to Marinari's paper, the example is as follows: start with some local Artinian ring $(Q,m)$ such that $Q$ is not Gorenstein. Then $Q[[X]]$ is complete, and one can find a local domain $R$ such that $\hat R=Q[[X]]$. Now if $R$ is a quotient of a regular local ring, then the comletion of $R$ is generically a complete intersection. But $Q[[X]]$ is not even generically Gorenstein, since $Q$ is not.

Comment: The same general idea was used by Ferrand and Raynaud in '70: http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASENS_1970_4_3_3_295_0

Comment: To fill in one detail in Hailong's answer, the fact that one can find a local domain $R$ with completion $Q[[x]]$ follows from a theorem of Lech (http://www.springerlink.com/content/y435pxn32m8q0703/): a complete local ring is the completion of a local domain if and only if it has depth at least one and no integer is a zerodivisor.  These are the obvious necessary conditions; that they are sufficient is (to me, still) very surprising.

Comment: That is an amazing paper title, by the way.

Comment: @Graham: thanks a lot for the details.  