# Is a Gorenstein ring a quotient of a local complete intersection

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

The title says it all - Suppose you are given a noetherian Gorenstein local ring $(A,m,k)$ of finite Krull dimension.

Does there exist a local complete intersection ring $B$ such that $A$ is a homomorphic image of $B$?

In the answer to this question

[A local ring not a quotient of a regular local ring](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21286/a-local-ring-not-a-quotient-of-a-regular-local-ring)

This paper was given

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200623014821/https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.nmj/1118785530)

where there is an example of a Gorenstein ring which is not a quotient of a regular ring, but it is not clear to me if it cannot be expressed as a quotient of a local complete intersection.

Comment: What is your definition of a local complete intersection ring?  For me, every such ring is a quotient of a regular local ring.  Thus the negative answer to the original question implies a negative answer to this question.

Comment: I thought that c.i means that its completion is a quotient of a regular local ring...

Comment: "I thought that c.i. means that its completion is a quotient of a regular local ring."  I guess that you are correct, at least according to Matsumura.  In algebraic geometry, there is a relative notion of local complete intersection, e.g., "LCI morphisms" or an "LCI $R$-algebra" $A$.  That definition definitely does require that $A$ is Zariski locally a quotient of a smooth $R$-algebra.  So the different usages are somewhat inconsistent.

Comment: And they are not equivalent: http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.4921

Answer (score 16):

No. A quotient of a local complete intersection ring has complete intersection formal fibers and so its complete intersection locus is open. In "Greco-Marinari, Nagata's Criterion and Openness of Loci for Gorenstein and Complete Intersection, Math. Z 160 (1978), 207-216", Example 4.3, there is an example of a local Gorenstein ring that do not satisfy this property.